# How do I properly return a CollectionViewCell with reuseIdentifier if weak self is nil in RxDataSource function?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, rx-swift, rxdatasources

I have an issue where [unowned self] was changed to [weak self] within the dataSource function used for a CollectionView using RxDataSource due to a memory leak. I now received a crash from returning a blank collectionViewCell that doesn't have a reuseIdentifier. I understand that I need to return a cell with a reuseID.

What changes are suggested to deal with this properly?

Someone suggested making collectionView.dataSource = nil in viewDidLoad() would fix this...

I was thinking instead of returning CanvasItemCollectionViewCell() in the 'guard' check,
I return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(for: indexPath, cellType: CanvasItemCollectionViewCell.self), but if self = self fails wouldn't that mean the collectionView is garbage?

This is a difficult problem to debug because this crash doesn't happen consistently.

Here are some screenshots to portray what I am looking at.

#### **RxDataSource code:**

```
func dataSource()
        -> RxCollectionViewSectionedAnimatedDataSource<CanvasSectionModel> {
        RxCollectionViewSectionedAnimatedDataSource<CanvasSectionModel>(
            animationConfiguration: AnimationConfiguration(
                insertAnimation: .fade,
                reloadAnimation: .fade,
                deleteAnimation: .fade
            ),
            configureCell: { [weak self] dataSource, collectionView, indexPath, _ in
                guard let self = self else { return CanvasItemCollectionViewCell() }
                
                switch dataSource[indexPath] {
                case let .CellModel(model):
                    let cell = collectionView
                        .dequeueReusableCell(
                            for: indexPath,
                            cellType: CanvasItemCollectionViewCell.self
                        )

                    cell.model = model

                    cell.onDeleteHandler = { _ in
                        self.presentDeleteConfirmation { deleteConfirmed in
                            guard deleteConfirmed else { return }
                            self.viewModel.inputs.deletePage(withProofID: model.id)
                        }
                    }

                    return cell
                }
            }
```

#### **Crash**:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, the problem is here:

```
cell.onDeleteHandler = { _ in
    self.presentDeleteConfirmation { deleteConfirmed in
        guard deleteConfirmed else { return }
        self.viewModel.inputs.deletePage(withProofID: model.id)
    }
}
```

Don't use `self` and you won't have a problem with self references so you won't need to import a weak self and then worry about the guard let self...

- For the first `self` reference, replace it with `UIViewController.top()` (see below for implementation.)
- For the second `self` reference, capture `viewModel` instead.

```
extension UIViewController {
    static func top() -> UIViewController {
        guard let rootViewController = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController else { fatalError("No view controller present in app?") }
        var result = rootViewController
        while let vc = result.presentedViewController, !vc.isBeingDismissed {
            result = vc
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up just encapsulating the entire assignment of the `onDeleteHandler` to a closure like so `func dataSource(onDelete: @escaping (CanvasEntity)->() )` and `cell.onDeleteHandler = { _ in onDelete(model) }`  allowing me to remove both self references. Thanks